# select all checkboxes of Listview in android

Tags: android

I'am having **Custom dialog** in which i've displayed a **listView** with **checkboxes**.I want to select all checkBoxes of ListView by Clicking button in dialog.

here is my button onClickListener

```
selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
          LinearLayout myLayout =(LinearLayout)listView.getChildAt(i);
          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
          cb.setChecked(true);
               }
            }
        });
```

with above code i have can only check those checkboxes which are on view.
I know this happens because listView reuses views.
please suggest me what to do

Comment: you can add boolean in listview model class that set to true when dialog button click, and in your listview adapter check if (boolean==true)checkbox.setchecked(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add boolean variable into your model class and set true on your button click listener, check this:

```
         class YourModel{
            public boolean isSelected() {
                return isSelected;
            }

            public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                isSelected = selected;
            }
          }
```

Your button onClick change.

```
              public void onClick(View view) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < yourArrayList.size(); i++) {
                        yourArrayList.get(i).setSelected(true);
                    }
                    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

your adapter getView method

```
          public View getView ( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
             CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            cb.setChecked(yourModel.isSelected());
          }
```

Comment: can u tell me one  more thing. after selecting checkbox when i close and reopen it all the checkboxes that i have selected should keep selected.

Comment: do you want it all should be get selected ri8 ?

Comment: if yes then put one boolean flag in your application share preference as "is_selected" true= if selected else false & get this flag on your activity onCreate method, base of this flag do it selected mark, also onClick store this value on your application shared preference.